# Python3.6: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values

Tags: python, python-3.6

My script is working fine on Pycharm with python 3.6, but has some issues when i run from ubuntu 16 using Python3.6

Error:

> python3.6 AttributeInsertion.py
>       Loading library modules...
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
>           sectiondict = self._sections[section]
>       KeyError: 'test_configurations'
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "AttributeInsertion.py", line 49, in <module>
>     jsonFeatureFile = readstringconfigfile('test_configurations', 'resourceName')
>   File "AttributeInsertion.py", line 15, in readstringconfigfile
>     fieldvalue = parser.get(section, field)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 781, in get
>     d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1141, in _unify_values
>     raise NoSectionError(section)
> configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'test_configurations'
> Error in sys.excepthook:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
>     from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
>     from apport.report import Report
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
>     import apport.fileutils
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
>     import apt
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
>     import apt_pkg
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
>
> Original exception was:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
>     sectiondict = self._sections[section]
> KeyError: 'test_configurations'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "AttributeInsertion.py", line 49, in <module>
>     jsonFeatureFile = readstringconfigfile('test_configurations', 'resourceName')
>   File "AttributeInsertion.py", line 15, in readstringconfigfile
>     fieldvalue = parser.get(section, field)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 781, in get
>     d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1141, in _unify_values
>     raise NoSectionError(section)
> configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'test_configurations'
> ```

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from time import sleep
import json
import datetime
import requests

print('Loading library modules...')


def readstringconfigfile(section, field):
    try:
        parser = ConfigParser()
        configfilename = "..\\resources\\config.ini"
        parser.read(configfilename)
        fieldvalue = parser.get(section, field)
        print(f'Read string config file {fieldvalue}.')
        return fieldvalue[1:-1]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Cannot find the config file.")


def replace_property_value(property, value):
    try:
        print('Old ' + property + ': ' + feature['properties'][property])  # print old value
        feature['properties'][property] = value  # override old value with new
        print('New ' + property + ': ' + feature['properties'][property])
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


def replace_payload_value(value):
    try:
        print('Old payload: ' + feature['properties']['payload'][0])
        feature['properties']['payload'][0] = value
        print('New payload: ' + feature['properties']['payload'][0])
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


def replace_user_name(value):
    try:
        print(feature['properties']['user']['name'])
        feature['properties']['user']['name'] = value
        print('New payload: ' + feature['properties']['user']['name'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


jsonFeatureFile = readstringconfigfile('test_configurations', 'resourceName')
jsonFeatureFile = "{0}{1}".format("..\\resources\\", jsonFeatureFile)
print(f'Resource file name is {jsonFeatureFile}.')

xyzSitBearerToken = readstringconfigfile('sit_configurations', 'xyzSitBearerToken')
xyzSitBearerToken = "\"" + xyzSitBearerToken + "\""
print(f'XYZ Bearer Token is {xyzSitBearerToken}.')

# Read FeatureCollection from JSON file:
print('Reading FeatureCollection from JSON file.')
with open(jsonFeatureFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    try:
        featureJson = json.load(f)
        print('Opening FeatureCollection.json', f)
        #print(f'Raw feature from resource file is {json.dumps(rawFeatureJson, indent=4)}.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(xyzSitBearerToken)}
        e2eXyzSemiPerm = readstringconfigfile('sit_configurations', 'e2eXyzSemiPerm')
        e2eXyzBaseUrl = readstringconfigfile('sit_configurations', 'e2eXyzBaseUrl')
        xyzPutUrl = e2eXyzBaseUrl + e2eXyzSemiPerm + "/features"
        print(f'PUT request to XYZ url - {xyzPutUrl}.')

        for feature in featureJson['attributes']:

            currentTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ')
            print(f'Current Time is {currentTime}.')
            replace_property_value("creationTime", currentTime)
            replace_property_value("startTime", currentTime)
            replace_property_value("informationType", "gottlieb-sit-semi-permanent")
            replace_payload_value("0xFF")
            replace_user_name("Pradeep Thomas Thundiyil")

            print(f'PUT Feature - {json.dumps(feature, indent=4)}.')
            response = requests.put(xyzPutUrl, json=feature, headers=headers)
            print(f'PUT feature to XYZ url - {response.url}.')
            print(f'PUT request response to XYZ {response.text}.')
            print(f'Response of PUT request to XYZ {response.status_code}.')
            print(response.json)
            print(f'Sleeping for 20 seconds.')
            sleep(20)
    except KeyError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: it looks like you don't have the `apt_pkg` dependency installed... Install it and post your results. (sudo) `pip3 install apt_pkg`

Comment: pip3 install apt_pkg
Collecting apt_pkg
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apt_pkg (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for apt_pkg

Comment: doesn't work lolz

Answer (score 0):

Here the path provided in the variable 'configfilename' is not pointing towards the exact location of config.ini file.
Default directories can be different according to the environments/servers/modules/etc; which is not the directory in which your program exists. So, you can make the code point towards the current directory where the file exists.

You can try by importing OS module(import os) and following changes in your variable 'configfilename' which directs to 'config.ini' file under the directory 'resources'.

```
configfilename = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'resources','config.ini'))
```